# UITableView willSelectRow method

Tags: uitableview, select

I have a tableView here, and its cell is a little bit different since I add a textField to the cell in order to input something, the UI looks like this:
[image: It is a table view cell with a textField inside it]

while intantiating the cell, I use code like this:

```
[cell.contentView addSubview: myTextField];
```

Then, comes the problem:
in the willSelectRow method, I just write this:

```
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return nil;
}
```

But, in the built app, this row can still be highlighted because of a touch, it just soon recover when finger leaves the screen,

I mean, this cell will still turn to blue for a short moment, or in the debugger, it will become blue just before the willSelectRow method returns a nil.

can anyone help me find the problem?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guess you should also set the selection style to None in the GetCell override?

Comment: Thanks a lot! That works! But why is returning a nil in willSelect method not enough?

Comment: From documentation: "This method is not called until users touch a row and then lift their finger; the row isn't selected until then, although it is highlighted on touch-down. You can use UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone to disable the appearance of the cell highlight on touch-down. This method isn’t called when the table view is in editing mode (that is, the editing property of the table view is set to YES) unless the table view allows selection during editing (that is, the allowsSelectionDuringEditing property of the table view is set to YES)."

Comment: And the documentatioon link: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html